# How to filter/delete subsets in a column of a Spark Dataset using Scala?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Dataset with only one column of type `Array[String]`.

```
+------------------------+
|                    col |
+------------------------+
|["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"]|
|["BB", "CC", "DD"]      |
|["AA","CC"]             |
|["EE", "FF", "GG"]      |
|["FF"]                  |
|["EE", "GG"]            |
|["KK", "LL", "MM"]      |
+------------------------+
```

I want to filter/delete those rows from dataset that are subset of other rows, so that the resultant dataset would look like the following:

```
    +------------------------+
    |                    col |
    +------------------------+
    |["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"]|
    |["EE", "FF", "GG"]      |
    |["KK", "LL", "MM"]      |
    +------------------------+
```

Here  `["BB", "CC", "DD"]` and `["AA","CC"]` are the subsets of `["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"]`, and `["FF"]` and `["EE", "GG"]` are the subsets of `["EE", "FF", "GG"]`. So those subsets will be eliminated from the resultant dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You Array[String].map() into Array[Set], then use subsetOf to filter the Array[Set]